# Digispark ATtiny 85 erases flash after power loss

Tags: arduino-ide, attiny85, digispark

I have some issues with my Digispark ATtiny85 board. 
If I upload the blink sketch for example the LED starts blinking and everything looks fine. But as soon as I unplug the Digispark from the USB port and plug it back in nothing happens. I know that the programm starts with a delay of 5 seconds so programming via USB becomes possible, but still nothing. Its seems like the flash-memory (where the programm is stored) of the ATtiny 85 is empty.

Here is the example blink sketch:

```
// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {                
  // initialize the digital pin as an output.
  pinMode(0, OUTPUT); //LED on Model B
  pinMode(1, OUTPUT); //LED on Model A   
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(0, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  digitalWrite(1, HIGH);
  delay(1000);               // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(0, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  digitalWrite(1, LOW); 
  delay(1000);               // wait for a second
}
```

I also tried uploading the sketch from a Laptop running on Windows but without success.

I am using Linux Mint and Arduino IDE 1.8.10.

Since I am new to Microcontrollers, I would be grateful for explainations, tipps or useful links. 
Thank you!

Comment: How is the eeprom used? Or you're confusing program memory (flash) with eeprom? The programmer selection is for flashing code (or bootloader by next menu item) into it over ISP connection using some programmer.

Comment: The code is saved in flash, not in EEPROM. The blink sketch does not use the EEPROM. So the actual problem is: You have a running blink sketch, but if you unplug the digispark and again plug it in, the blink sketch isn't running anymore?

Comment: `Or could a floating reset pin be the reason for this behavior?` the official digispark has the reset pin disabled, so you get an extra GPIO pin. So it can't be a floating reset pin.

Comment: Okay I confused flash with EEPROM. Thanks for pointing this out, I will change that in the question. @chrisl Yes that's my problem

Comment: I found that on the digistump forum: "I get the same behavior, except Arduino 1.6.5-r5.  5 boards all exhibit the same behavior.  These do not say "Digispark" on them; just "ATttiny" (85"https://digistump.com/board/index.php?topic=3161.0)
Might this problem be related to the arduino IDE?

Comment: I got the same issue, on two boards. Will probably try to burn the bootloader using usbasp, maybe they burned the wrong one back in china.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue, on two boards. Will probably try to burn the bootloader using usbasp, maybe they burned the wrong one back in china.

EDIT:

As expected flashing the micronucleus bootloader using USBasp solved the problem on both of the boards. I've used burn-o-mat as the arduino was not seeing my programmer.

Just download the firmware from github (I've used this: https://github.com/f4goh/micronucleus/archive/master.zip )

and connect like so (here the guy is using arduino uno, doesn't matter): https://hamprojects.wordpress.com/2018/12/27/digispark-microcontrollers-implementation/